# R - alternating thick/thin lines between points

Tags: r

I am trying to produce a figure with alternating thick/thin lines between points, an example data structure looks like this:

```
    V1   V2  V3
1   2    0  BG
2   2 1510  BG
3   1 1710  BG
4   2 2000  BG
5   1 2500  BG
6   2 2700  BG
7   2    0 BG2
8   2  510 BG2
9   1  710 BG2
10  2 1000 BG2
11  1 3500 BG2
12  2 3700 BG2
```

So far I used this command:

```
xyplot(bg$V3~bg$V2,type="b",group=bg$V3,lwd=20)
```

[image]

However, what I need is to have, for BG for example, 0-1510 as a thick line (lwd=20) and then 1510-1710 as a thin line (e.g. lwd=1),  1710-2000 as lwd=20, 2000-2500 as lwd=1, and finally 2500-2700 as a lwd=20

I know this is a bit of a strange problem, but do you think it is possible to do? I tried an ifelse statement but it appears you can't define two types of line in the same plot.

Thanks,
Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- read.table(text="V1   V2  V3
 2    0  BG
 2 1510  BG
 1 1710  BG
 2 2000  BG
 1 2500  BG
 2 2700  BG
 2    0 BG2
 2  510 BG2
 1  710 BG2
  2 1000 BG2
  1 3500 BG2
  2 3700 BG2", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=V2, y=V3, size=V1, group=V3, color=V3))
gg <- gg + geom_line()
gg
```

[image]